# Using temp variable produces different result with an array

Tags: bash, macos, terminal

Can someone help me explain the difference temp variable makes as I'm adding elements to an array?

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a finaldirs1
declare -a finaldirs2

declare -a files=("Planes" "Trains" "Automobiles")

echo "A)..................................."
for el1 in "${files[@]}"; do
    tmpe=$(printf "1:%s." "${el1}")
    finaldirs1+=($tmpe)
done
for elA in "${finaldirs1[@]}"; do
    echo "First: " $elA
done

echo "B)..................................."
for el2 in "${files[@]}"; do
    finaldirs2+=$(printf "2:%s." "${el2}")
done
for elB in "${finaldirs2[@]}"; do
    echo "Second: " $elB
done
echo "DONE................................."
```

In short, second version has all the elements together somehow. The output:

```
A)...................................
First:  1:Planes.
First:  1:Trains.
First:  1:Automobiles.
B)...................................
Second:  2:Planes.2:Trains.2:Automobiles.
DONE.................................
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed a couple of parentheses.

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a finaldirs1
declare -a finaldirs2

declare -a files=("Planes" "Trains" "Automobiles")

echo "A)..................................."
for el1 in "${files[@]}"; do
    tmpe=$(printf "1:%s." "${el1}")
    finaldirs1+=($tmpe)
done
for elA in "${finaldirs1[@]}"; do
    echo "First: " $elA
done

echo "B)..................................."
for el2 in "${files[@]}"; do
    finaldirs2+=($(printf "2:%s." "${el2}"))
done
for elB in "${finaldirs2[@]}"; do
    echo "Second: " $elB
done
echo "DONE................................."
```

You see, appending to an array it's done like `arr+=('element')`, while `arr+='element'` would just append to the string `arr`.

Answer (score 2):

```
finaldirs2+=$(printf "2:%s." "${el2}")
```

Should be

```
finaldirs2+=($(printf "2:%s." "${el2}"))
```